# Most efficient way caching major places from geocode

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

In line with Googles TOC when geocoding I want to cache the results to reduce the load on their server. I also want to store geocode results as efficentily as possible, without including street numbers and street names. Here is an example address that I would be working with:

> 275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA

```
Types: street_number                    # 275-291
Types: route                            # Bedford Ave
Types: Administrative_area_level_3      # Brooklyn
Types: administrative_area_level_2      # Kings
Types: administrative_area_level_1      # New York
Types: Country                          # USA
```

How would one recommend I do this as efficiently as possible. I was thinking of having four tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE locality (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
loc varchar(255),
size varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE administrative_area_level_1 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
loc varchar(255),
rad varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE administrative_area_level_2 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
loc varchar(255),
rad varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE administrative_area_level_3 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
loc varchar(255),
rad varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE country (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
loc varchar(255),
rad varchar(255)
);
```

Then when I try and recall it I would look from the highest level (Country -> Level3, Level2, Level1) to see if I can find it. That way I always find the most significant enty matching that value.

I'm new to SQL so does this structure make sense from a storage and recollection point of view?

Comment: Do you know about foreign keys? They are missing in your model.

Comment: Based on your information I added primary keys. Is that not right. Also, do I even need a primary key, they most likely will not be linked together

Comment: If is there a hierarchy like in "New York and Los Angeles belong to US and not to Spain" then you need to **constrain** the values on the lower levels to what exists in the upper levels. Hence the foreign keys.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto could you show me an example please? Also what do you think to daisy chaining the tables, i.e link level2 to level3, then level3 to level4

Comment: Have you considered nosql database as storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain the values in lower levels to those existent in upper levels using foreign keys

```
create table administrative_area_level_1 (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    loc varchar(255),
    rad varchar(255)
);

create table administrative_area_level_2 (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    loc varchar(255),
    rad varchar(255),
    level_1_id int references administrative_area_level_1 (id)
);
```

The `serial` type will create an integer sequence. Primary key implies not null.

The `references` means it must exist in the referenced table.

```
insert into administrative_area_level_1 (name, loc, rad) values
('New York', 'some_loc', 'some_rad');

insert into administrative_area_level_2 (name, loc, rad, level_1_id) values
('Kings', 'some_loc', 'some_rad', 1);
```

Now if I try to insert into a referencing table a value that does not exist in the referenced table I get an error

```
insert into administrative_area_level_2 (name, loc, rad, level_1_id) values
('Kings', 'some_loc', 'some_rad', 2);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "administrative_area_level_2" violates foreign key constraint "administrative_area_level_2_level_1_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (level_1_id)=(2) is not present in table "administrative_area_level_1".
```

In the addresses table you will reference all the five tables you posted.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll look into this now. Do I need autoincrement or not?

Comment: `SERIAL` *is* auto-increment: "`SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`." ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html))